# SQL How count subset with condition

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
+--------+------------+----------------+
| saleId | saleDate   | contractId     |
+--------+------------+----------------+
| 1      | 01.07.2016 | 1001           |
| 2      | 02.07.2016 | 1001           |
| 3      | 03.07.2016 | 1002           |
| 4      | 04.07.2016 | 1002           |
| 5      | 05.07.2016 | 1001           |
| 6      | 06.07.2016 | 1001           |
+--------+------------+----------------+
```

I want to count number of previuos sales by contract for each sale (each row)

```
+--------+------------+------------+------------------------+
| saleId | saleDate   | contractId | SalesCountPerContract  |
+--------+------------+------------+------------------------+
| 1      | 01.07.2016 | 1001       | 0                      |
| 2      | 02.07.2016 | 1001       | 1                      |
| 3      | 03.07.2016 | 1002       | 0                      |
| 4      | 04.07.2016 | 1002       | 1                      |
| 5      | 05.07.2016 | 1001       | 2                      |
| 6      | 06.07.2016 | 1001       | 3                      |
+--------+------------+------------+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  t.*
       ,row_number() over 
            (partition by contractId order by saleDate) - 1 as SalesCountPerContract  

from    mytable t
```

Comment: ,Your answer is always very simple and very efficient.It's very useful to me.

Comment: Thats great idea! Thanks.